# Get files from github without installing git using php script

Tags: php, github, pull

My client allocates a linux server without root access and git installed. I would like to pull my codes from github using a php script.

I googled this issue for last few hours. But no solution found.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Why not install git though? I presume cPanel provides a git way too.

Comment: @nice_dev This is a VPS and have no cpanel.

Comment: Fetch `https://github.com/VND/PKG/archive/master.zip` with `copy()` and do some unzipping.

Comment: @s.k.paul mario suggested a good way. An alternative is to do git pull on your machine and use sftp to push it, however this would take longer time if project is huge.

Comment: GitHub provides the ability to download your repo as a zip file. So you could do that and then unzip it. Don't need PHP for that, standard command line tools can do it

Comment: Or just ask your client to install git for you, if you need it

Answer (score 2):

So i guess you need to use github REST Api.
[Github REST](https://docs.github.com/en/rest)

Comment: I've had a look on the docs. But not found anything alternative to git pull